# RxJS How to map a stream to the latest of a different stream?

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs, cyclejs

I'm currently using Cycle.js and I'm attempting to get a stream for a text input when a form is submitted. For example:

```
const textChange$ = DOMSource.select('input').events('change');
const textValueSubmit$ = DOMSource.select('form').events('submit')
    .do(ev => ev.preventDefault());
```

I think I need to merge the streams at this point but I only care about the latest text value (when the user has submitted the form). What is the appropriate way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the current answers, you also have the possibility to use `withLatestFrom`. Note that `combineLatest` and `withLatestFrom` semantics differ on subtle points:

- combineLatest will emit a value whenever one of the combined sources emits a value (**so long as each of the source observable sequences has emitted at least one element**)
- withLatestFrom will emit a value only when the combining source emits a value

So you could do for instance :

```
const textChange$ = DOMSource.select('input').events('change')
  .pluck('target', 'value')
const submit$ = DOMSource.select('form').event('submit')
  .do(ev => ev.preventDefault)
const textValueSubmit$ = submit$.withLatestFrom(textChange$, function (submit, textChange){...});
```

Even if this does not cover more than your particular use case (here you don't care about the value passed on by the submit event, so as suggested `sample` also works fine), it is still good to keep those two operators in mind for another similar future use case.

Last thing, does `combineLatest` really works for you in this case? It seems that you will have a `textValueSubmit$` emission every time `textChange$` fires. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: Good catch--combineLatest doesn't really work because of the emission every time textChange$ fires, which was not my intension.

Comment: alright, I was right to check with you then. Don't forget to upvote answers when they are useful by the way. Those are important SO guidelines. Also, if your answer is not correct, it is a good practice you should remove it so newcomers to the thread do not get confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sample()` to avoid creating the extra function, I believe this is the functionality you're looking for

```
const textChange$ = DOMSource.select('input').events('change')
  .pluck('target', 'value')
const submit$ = DOMSource.select('form').event('submit')
  .do(ev => ev.preventDefault)
const textValueSubmit$ = textChange$.sample(submit$)
```